# Values $l$ for which $l=\int_{0}^{l}f(t)dt$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

A simple question (I think): if $l=\int_{0}^{l}f(t)dt$, where $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a continuous function and $l$ a real number, then can we justify that $l=0$ is the only solution by the mean value theorem?

Comment: It is not true: take $f=1$

Comment: The MVT would just state that $l\in[0,1]$

Comment: @Maksim It would if $f(x)=1$, otherwise it can be used to gain insight in the problem efficently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Differentiating both sides and using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we nave:

$\frac{d}{dl}l=\frac{d}{dl}\int_0^lf(t)dt$

$1=f(l)$

Thus, $l$ can be every value within the unit interval, as long as $f=1$, otherwise we need to have a fixed $l$

**Method 2:**

Using MVT we get:

$l=f(c)l$ for some $c\in [0,l]$

This holds without problem if $f(t)=1$
If instead $f≠1$, $l$ cannot vary.

With both the methods we obtained that if $f=1$, $l$ could be every number (in the unit interval), but if instead $f≠1$, $l$ cannot vary.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, it is helpful!!! Thanks!!!